# why i am able to select non aggregated column in sql which is not present in group by clause in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

why i am able to select non aggregated column in sql which is not present in group by clause?

```
create table Championships(year integer,
                           Wimbledon integer,
                           Fr_open integer,
                           US_open integer,
                           Au_open integer);
                       
CREATE TABLE Players(player_id INTEGER,
                     player_name string);
                       
insert into Championships VALUES(2018,1,1,1,1);
insert into Championships VALUES(2019,1,1,2,2);
insert into Championships VALUES(2020,2,1,2,2);

insert into Players VALUES(1,'Nadal');
insert into Players VALUES(2,'Federer');
insert into Players VALUES(3,'Novak');


                       
select grand as player_id, p.player_name, count(grand) as grand_slams_count from (
    select Wimbledon as grand from Championships
    union all
    select Fr_open as grand from Championships
    union all
    select US_open as grand from Championships
    union all
    select Au_open as grand from Championships) as c 
left join Players p on c.grand = p.player_id
group by 1;
```

I am getting result like this -

```
1 Nadal 14
2 Federer 5
```

isn't it should have throwed an error something like - 'cannot select non-aggregated column which is not present in group by clause'?

Comment: Because of `Only Full Group By` - see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: @Barmar Ah, I see that now. Good point.

Comment: Historically, MySQL didn't enforce that requirement. Around 5.6 they added a setting `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to make it an error, but it was off by default. In 5.7 they changed the default to on, but you can turn it off for backward compatibility.

Comment: Note that even with this setting on, MySQL allows your query. `p.player_name` is functionally dependent on the grouped column `p.player_id`, so there's a unique value in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled (the default since MySQL 5.7.5), it implements the following rule:

> Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns.

In your example, there's no error because `Players.player_name` is functionally dependent on the group by column `Players.player_id`.